# Minimal infra-red communication distances

Tags: mosfet, infrared, remote

[image]

I am having a problem establishing a practical IrLed communication transmission/reception distance in low ambient light levels with devices:

[IrLed TSAL6200](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0df4/0900766b80df46d5.pdf)

[IR Remote Reciever TSOP38238](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0e56/0900766b80e56a95.pdf)

I am using a 38kHz test signal.

When driving the TSAL6200 (1.28 volts maximum across it) directly by an Atmega328-P the TSOP38238 responds only up to 1.4 meters distance.

When driving the TSAL6200 (1.32 volts maximum across it) via an N-channel MOSFET 2N7000 (NOT ALLOWED THIRD DATASHEET LINK) the TSOP38238 responds only up to 1.7 meters distance.

When driving three TSAL6200's in parallel via the MOSFET 2N7000 (1.32 volts maximum across each) the TSOP38238 responds only up to 2.4 meters distance.

The MOSFET circuits increase the time for the voltage across the IrLed to fall. This voltage is only falling to 680mV before rising again (please see attachment V-IrLed(Vishay)viaMOSFET.jpg).

Is this issue inhibiting the transmission/reception performance?

Would the inclusion of a Zener Diode across the MOSFET help?

Suggestions for other improvements?

[image: Voltage/IrLed TSAL6200]

Unlabelled waveform is the 2N7000 gate voltage with respect to ground.

The voltage across the IrLed series resistor = 3.455 volts. I/IrLed = 3.455/40ohm = 86.4mA.

The voltage across th IrLed series resistor = -18mV when LOW.

IrLed current is 86.4mA, below 100mA maximum. 2N7000 has maximum constant current of 350mA. Which different parameters do you suggest in a 'modern' mosfet alternative?

Comment: The diode is backwards in your diagram. Is it backwards in the actual circuit?

Comment: What does the voltage at the gate of the 2n7000 look like? You should make sure that the transistor is being driven properly before guessing about other solutions.

Comment: How about the voltage across the 40 ohm resistor? That would tell us how much _current_ is flowing through the LED, which is much more important than the voltage across it. If there is very little current flowing through the LED then leakage currents might give you 0.68 V across the diode even though the diode is completely dark.

Comment: You say that the voltage across the resistor is 3.4V. I'm assuming that it has _two_ voltages, one when the transistor is conducting and one when it is not. What is the resistor voltage when the transistor is _not_ conducting (when the gate voltage is at ground)?

Comment: I see you have the current sent to 100mA which is the maximum for the LED. If you've connected three in parallel that would exceed the maximum and even for 100mA it's probably not a very good MOSFET when Vgs is that low - you'd probably be better finding a more modern better one.

Comment: How are you measuring the voltage across the diode?  Are you using a differential probe, or subtracting 2 channels on the scope?  That waveform doesn't look correct to me, the FET should shut off quickly.  It doesn't have huge output capacitance.

Answer (score 1):

One detail about these IR detectors is that they don't detect a constant carrier well. The 38Khz should be on/off modulated with something like the 600uS period signal shown on page 3 of the data sheet.[image]